# запуск php+mysql скрипта в командной строке

Tags: php, mysql

Есть настроенный веб-сервер с php, mysql.
Через браузер все работает хорошо, решил запустить php скрипт из командной строки, чтобы потом сделать батник, а php ругается что не видит расширение mysqli.

```
Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\localhost\www\add.php
```

Естественно оно включено, работает, ведь через веб все нормально отрабатывает.
В модулях через `php -m` mysqli присутствует

Answer (score 1):

Решилось добавлением ключа -с с абсолютным путем до php.ini.

```
php -c "C:\php\php.ini"
```